# Fully stop a youtube video on closing a DIV container (containing the Youtube Iframe)

Tags: jquery, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-api

I have a page with a list of Movies, and all of them have their Trailer which is the Youtube Iframe.

You can check it here: 
http://www.edoramedia.com/boxofficeuae/

Click on a video thumbnail, you can see the preview and details of that particular movie. Click on the play button to start watching the trailer, now if you click on the close button or click on another thumbnail, even though the container's changed, still the previous trailer is playing in the background.

I'm using Jquery for this project. So is there a way to stop a trailer on close?

Comment: Can you not reduce this problem down to the smallest component? You should be able to get it down to a 10-20-line testcase of code that goes in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm using the Iframe embed, it wasn't really easy for me to implement this method and also using the [Youtube API](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html) is still in the beta mode for now. I used [this plugin](http://tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin) and it worked very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `.hide()` function for the div containing the video iframe

Comment: No it doesn't work with hide(), because even though the DIV container is kinda hidden but still the video inside it is still paying in the background, so when I open another video and start playing there will be a mix of 2 video sounds!

Comment: you can make the html of that particular video id to "" using. .html("");

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to access to the youtube video and issue the `stopVideo` event

```
player.stopVideo();
```

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_controls

Comment: Since I'm using the Iframe embed, it wasn't really easy for me to implement this method and also using the Youtube API is still in the beta mode for now (http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html). I used this plugin: http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin and it worked very nicely.